# Sitecatalyst's custom-link request not sends in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, adobe-analytics

I have problems with tracking Sitecatalyst custom-link analytics in IE.
If I open a page in IE and click on some link (`href=#`) with analytics - 
`s.tl(...)` method is called and analytics are sent.
After clicking on this link for a second time (without reloading the page) - `s.tl(...)` is called but analytics are not sent.

In FireFox and Chrome everything is ok - analytics are sent every time the link is clicked.

Has anyone faced this problem?

I'm using H.24.2 version of sitecatalyst and IE9.
Link coded next way

```
HTML:
  <a class="web-analytics-custom-link" 
    href="/content/en/customer-service/contact-us.html" 
    data-custom-link="{'linkName':'footer_contact us', 'vars' : 'prop1,pageName'}">
        Contact us
  </a>

JS:
 function recordCustomLink(params) {
    if (s != null) {
        if (params.customVars) {
           jQuery.each(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(params.customVars)), function(i, val) {
               s[i] = val;
           });
        }
        var eventsCopy = s.events;
        if (params.events) {
            s.linkTrackEvents =  params.events;
            $.each(params.events.split(','), function(index, val){
                s.events = s.apl(s.events, val, ",",2);
            });
        } else {
            s.linkTrackEvents = 'None';
        }
        if (params.vars) {
            s.linkTrackVars = params.vars;
        } else {
            s.linkTrackVars = 'None';
        }
        if (params.customData) {
            s.setCustomData(JSON.stringify(params.customData));
        }
        if(params.linkObject && params.linkObject.href){
            var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
            var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1 && ua.indexOf("mobile");
            s.tl(isAndroid || params.linkObject, 'o', unescape(params.linkName));
        } else{
            s.tl(true, 'o', unescape(params.linkName));
        }
        s.events = eventsCopy;
    }
}

$(document).on('mouseup touchend','.web-analytics-custom-link', function (e) {
    var waParams = $(this).data('custom-link');
    if(!waParams.linkObject){
        if($(this)[0].href){
            waParams.linkObject = $(this)[0];
        }
    }
    if (waParams) {
        recordCustomLink(waParams);
    }
});
```

Comment: need more info.. what version of SC are you using? What version IE? How is the link coded? etc..

Comment: I'm using H.24.2 version of analytics and IE9, link coded next way